# HTACCESS - Multiple RedirectMatch Rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm working on a site fixing a few dead links; but I'm having an issue with my `RedirectMatch` directives.

```
RedirectMatch 301 "/treatmentsgenuine-dermaroller(.*)" http://example.com/treatments/genuine-dermaroller-therapy
RedirectMatch 301 "/treatments/genuine-dermaroller(.*)" http://example.com/treatments/genuine-dermaroller-therapy
```

These are to both correct the badly written link (top) to the page, and redirect requests to the original URL of this page (bottom). The URL had a trademark symbol in the URL, so I removed it for the sake of making it easier to type in/work with.

The only issues is, the site returns error 500 when both of these rules are in place. If I remove the second, it works fine. I've also had the same issue with every other `RedirectMatch` I've tried adding to the htaccess.

I've tried adding the `[L]` flag, out of a hunch, but this didn't seem to make a positive difference.

Is there anything wrong with this that I can't see?

Are multiple `RedirectMatch` directives even allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I managed to find was

```
RedirectMatch 301 "((treatmentsgenuine-dermaroller(.)-therapy)|(treatments/genuine-dermaroller(.)-therapy))" http://example.com/treatments/genuine-dermaroller-therapy
```

This way both variations of the URL are dealt with by the same rule, preventing the redirect loop pointed out to me by @anubhava.

Answer (score 1):

Replace both rules with just this one:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(treatments)/(genuine-dermaroller)((?!-therapy).*)$ /$1/$2-therapy
```

Your 2nd rule is also matching target URL and causing a redirection loop.

Comment: Oopsie. Just noticed that it's causing a redirect loop. Weirdly, Chrome doesn't say that it is. I had no luck with this, but I managed to find a workaround, I've posted as an answer. Thanks for your help anyway, and thanks for pointing the redirect loop out.

Comment: All you had to do was to leave a comment and I would have helped you further.  To my eyes your posted solution looks pretty complex for this simple task but as long as you;re happy :)